# asp.net 4.0 Random posting behavior

Tags: asp.net

At work, we are developing a complex webForms app.  We are using Visual Studio 2010 to develop a framework 4.0 site in C# 4.0.

We have been experiencing random behavior on post.  Here is what we have seen:

`<Button>` tag with a runat server and a ServerClick event will SOMETIMES run the Click event twice (Average 80% twice)  - Converted to asp:Button control and it always fired its click event once.  So, we called that 'fixed'.

`<asp:DropdownList>` control with `autopostback=true`.  We are seeing similar behavior.  We have two UserControls that have an `<asp:DropdownList>` with autopostback=true inside.  When two of these UserControls are displayed at the same time, If you click one of them, it calls the OnChange event for both DropdownLists. (Average 40% both called)

We have determined that this is not a client side issue.  Fiddler 2 shows that we are filling the EventTarget correctly and that both of the DropdownLists' values are correct on post.

At a guess, it seems that the __DoPostBack "part" of asp.net 4.0 has an issue since that is the only thing that these two similar issues shared.  Has anyone else seen issues like these and are their any tips/tricks to solve this?

(BTW, converting to a older version is not an option. We are heavily using some of the new features in 4.0)

Comment: Are there any differences between the HTTP requests in Fiddler?

Comment: Can you post some code?  If you're using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Intellitrace might help generate logs of the call stack, which could help identify the conditions under which this happens.

Comment: Can you post the code for how/where you're wiring up those event handlers?  Is it in markup or codebehind?

Comment: SLaks - Do you mean differences between when the odd behavior happens and when it does not? I cannot see any difference - So, I have to say, "No".

Comment: Dave - The odd thing is .. I've tried to do a Minimum working example, but I just cannot replicate the issue is a small setting ...

Comment: Dan - There is no attaching of the event. It is all done automagically between the asp.net page and the code behind page. So, we are just adding it into the asp.net code like this: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAndOr" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="AndOr_SelectedIndexChanged">

Comment: Dave - Intellitrace!  Will do!  We'll see.

Comment: From Intellitrace - It seems the random behavior is always followed by "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" (System.Net.SocketException)

also, the rate of random issues is lower when IIS is ran on a new Win 7 machine.  XP and Server 2008 Machines produce the error more frequently