# help styling the asp:button control using the Sliding Door technique

Tags: asp.net, css

due to a problem we are encountering with asp.net (see: [asp.net 4.0 Random posting behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319698/asp-net-4-0-random-posting-behavior)) we need to style asp:button controls (that of course resolve to <input type=submit> tags) using the sliding door technique.

We originally had <button><span>text</span></button> sets but because of the above issue we need to move to asp:Button controls.

You cannot put a <span> tag inside of an asp:button control, so working it like the above will not work.

I got it to work only in IE8 by wrapping the button with a div using "display: inline-block".  But it fails in IE7, so this is not a solution for us.  It needs to work in both IE7 & IE8 (Firefox would be great, but in not required)

Comment: Could you describe the behavior you expect using a "sliding door" technique, please?

Comment: "... flexible interface components which expand and contract with the size of the text can be created if we use two separate background images. One for the left, one for the right. Think of these two images as Sliding Doors that complete one doorway. The doors slide together and overlap more to fill a narrow space, or slide apart and overlap less to fill a wider space ..." 

A great definition can be found @
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Though, they are creating tabs, the concept works for any interactive dynamic element - such as a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix `display: inline-block;` for IE6-7 you can try

```
<div class="button"><input type="submit" /></div>


.button {
   display: inline;
   display: inline-block;
   zoom: 1;
}
```

(These styles are correct almost for any time you want simulate inline-block in all browsers)

Comment: Thanks, but as noted in the above question, I cannot use the <button> tag.  It must be the asp:Button control that resolves to the <input type=submit> tag

Comment: Ok, so you can wrap your input with inline-block element. It does not metter. Check edited answer

Comment: Right, that is exactly what I said I tried in my original text, but it fails in IE7 - Please re-read original question

Comment: ..."I got it to work only in IE8 by wrapping the button with a div using "display: inline-block"."... Right, but if you'll add `display: inline;` before `display: inline-block;` and `zoom: 1;` - that will fix IE7 issue with inline-blocks - they will work properly. Just have a try.

Comment: I apologize - I cannot test this until Monday.  But I will put it to the test first thing in the morning.  I really hope this works